# App crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an IPv6

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted the app to iTunes connect and it got rejected specifying that when it runs on IPV6 the app crashes. by noting that i submitted another app before with same 100% configuration, and using AFNetworking latest and it got accepted and almost same functionality. i have tested my app in release,debug build it didn't crash at all.

Text Quoted from apple rejection:

> 2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS Performance - 2.1
>
> Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an
>   IPv6 network when we:
>
> When we tried to create an account, we added a phone number and tapped
>   on "Done", app crashed.
>
> This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - Offline
> - On Wi-Fi
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

And they attached two crash logs its uploaded to (google drive) :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32ROW7V8Fj4M0JsS0NCNXNoWVk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32ROW7V8Fj4NFJtY1J5YU9KY1E/view?usp=sharing

The point is the crash logs it doesn't specify anything at all ! and the app it doesn't crash <.< i have tried it more than 1000 times and went through quality assurance and testing for over a month.

Comment: You need to check it on IPv6 only environment

Comment: have you solved it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scene the app never crashes at all and what Apple said about crashing the app doesn't make any since, The way to solve the issue was in two steps:

1- There has been a fix from server side where it was using Microsoft Assure without the support of IPV6, so a fix has been deployed to support IPV6 with a new base url for api requests.

2- In the past submit to the App Store i didn't provide a demo account for apple which i think it was also one of the cause why apple has rejected the app with unknown crash. so this time i did give them a demo account to access without going through registration.

Answer (score 0):

The code for inApp should have only one time transaction observer added like below.

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

should only written in didLoad() and it must be only one time. Then your Ap will be saved by crash. In App. I was at the same problem as yours.